# Assuming a lapsed patent

Tags: lapsed-patent

I noticed that the patent for solidifying forms with cremated ash such as in ceramics, glass, or paint, has lapsed due to non-payment. Does that mean that I can purchase the rights to the patent?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible to renew the patent if the lapse was in the close past. But the only way to to purchase a patent is by talking to the owner. There is no such thing as buying patents that others surrendered from the government or something alike.

But even if you do renew a patent by buying it shortly after the non payment of fees (you can look up the exact regulations for the renewment), please consider that nobody would not-pay the fees on a patent he considers valuable. Most of the times, not paying the fees is just a easier way of surrendering the patent (or application).

Answer (score 1):

If a patent has lapsed, there are no rights available anymore. In order for the patent rights to be available, one has to pay the annual fees.